# How can I drag drop QListWidget items with custom item widgets?

Tags: python, c++, qt, pyqt

If I use `QListWidget` default items, I can drag drop its items (thanks to `setDragDropMode`) but if I use a custom item widget (`setItemWidget`) I'm not able to drag drop. How can I fix that?

This is my code for make a list with custom widget items:

```
    alist = QListWidget()
    alist.setDragDropMode(QAbstractItemView.InternalMove)

    for i in range(20):
        itemWidget = QPushButton('Test' + str(i))
        item = QListWidgetItem('item ' + str(i))
        item.setSizeHint(QSize(0,100))
        alist.addItem(item)
        alist.setItemWidget(item, itemWidget)

    vbox = QVBoxLayout()
    vbox.addWidget(QPushButton())
    vbox.addWidget(alist)
    self.setLayout(vbox)
```

Comment: Fabrico : is their any specific reason why you are using listWidget rather than listView ?

Comment: @thecreator232 I actually dont know the difference between both. New on QT. I'm trying to make a layer component (text, preview icon, visibility button) and trying to put them in a scrollable component with drag drop support. So i dont need to code all that by hand.

Answer (score 0):

Check If this seems to work.

```
alist = QListWidget()
alist.setAcceptDrops(True)
alist.setDragEnabled(True)
alist.setDragDropMode(QAbstractItemView.InternalMove)

for i in range(20):
    itemWidget = QPushButton('Test' + str(i))
    item = QListWidgetItem('item ' + str(i))
    item.setSizeHint(QSize(0,100))
    alist.addItem(item)
    alist.setItemWidget(item, itemWidget)

vbox = QVBoxLayout()
vbox.addWidget(QPushButton())
vbox.addWidget(alist)
self.setLayout(vbox)
```